# Why do my Android app param names changed after uploading to playstore?

Tags: android, api, kotlin

I have an android app developed using Kotlin. Two days back I have uploaded a new version of my app in playstore console. After that update, none of my APIs worked. On having extensive research I found that my param names were changed automatically in the uploaded app.

Actual Params I was sending to API were like this (Same are sent to API in deug app): -

`{ "key":"My_Secret_Key", "fname":"First_Name", "lname":"Last_Name" }`

But after uploading the playstore my params became like this: -

`{ "a":"My_Secret_Key", "b":"First_Name", "c":"Last_Name" }`

Please anyone help me in this. I became mad from two days searching the internet for possible answers.

Note:- I have tried uploading the app again and again for atleast 4 to 5 times. But same issue. The same is working, When I pack the apk and use in on my mobile.

Thanks in advance.

*I have tried to upload another app to check whether app uploading error exists. but not of use.

I have also tried logging the requests and responses in logcat as well as toasts in the app. The app from playstore is outputting the different format than that one from my local machine.

I have searched Internet for the same from past two days but of no use.

I have also contacted Google PlayStore Support team on this issue. But still now no response from them.*

Comment: share what you tried so far in shape of code

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some library serializing a class, you may need to exempt that class from minification so the property names are not obfuscated by R8. Use `@Keep` on any class you are serializing to JSON.

Comment: Hi, If the serializing is the problem, then it shouldn't have worked in the debug-apk also. But however, when I test with debug-apk it is working fine. Problem happens only when I uploaded it to play store.

Comment: Are you obfuscating in your debug build? In a default Android Studio project, debug builds are not and release builds are.